# Calling Javascript using UIWebView

Tags: javascript, uiwebview, ios5, rgraph

I am trying to call a javascript in a html page using the function -

```
View did load function
{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writablePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"BasicGraph.html"];
    NSURL *urlStr = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:writablePath];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *myPathInfo = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BasicGraph" ofType:@"html"];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:myPathInfo toPath:writablePath error:NULL];

    [graphView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlStr]];
}

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [graphView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"methodName()"];
}
```

Here is the javascript on the html page -

```
<script>
    function methodName()
      {
         // code to draw graph
      }
```

However, the function `methodName()` is not getting called but after window.onload = function () everything is working fine..

I am trying to integrate [RGraphs](http://www.rgraph.net/) into my application and `Basic.html` is the html page in which the javascripts are written.

It would be great if someone could help me out with this.

Comment: Hey, if you don't mind can you please share your sample code where i can call rgrpahs from native iOS code? It will be very helpful. from last one week i am struggling to make it work.

Comment: I just created an elegant demo on the topic of Javascript run in UIWebview, please refer to :http://creiapp.blogspot.hk/2013/04/uiwebview-javascript.html

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Simple: You try to execute the JS function from Objective-C before the page even has been loaded.

Implement the [UIWebView's delegate method](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) `webViewDidFinishLoad:` in your UIViewController and in there you call `[graphView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"methodName()"];` to make sure the function gets called **after** the page has been loaded.

Comment: I tried to do that but still it is not working.. I have changed the code in the question but nothing seems to work..

Comment: it is a very valid question and not at all a stupid one.. thank you. i forgot to set the delegate.. and the code works now...

Answer (score 10):

To clarify a little bit more.

.h - implement the UIWebViewDelegate

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@end
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *path = @"http://www.google.com";
    [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]]];
    _webView.delegate = self; //Set the webviews delegate to this
}

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    //Execute javascript method or pure javascript if needed
    [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"methodName();"];
}
```

You could also assign the delegate from storyboard instead of doing it in the code.