# uiWebview call javascript function syntax

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, xcode

I am migrating my app from android to iOS and for following line, compiler returns me an error on iOS,

`webviewA.loadUrl("javascript:setVars(\"" + var1 + "\",\""  + var2 +  "\")");` //properly executed on Android

for iOS I am trying,

```
[webViewA stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"javascript:setVars(\"" + var1 + "\",\""  + var2 +  "\")"];
```

which would be correct syntax for iOS? Thank you.

Comment: for people who want an elegant demo on the topic of Javascript run in UIWebview, please refer to :http://creiapp.blogspot.hk/2013/04/uiwebview-javascript.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per [this answer on another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886443/calling-javascript-using-uiwebview), you need to implement the `UIWebView` delegate method `webViewDidFinishLoad:`, and in there implement `[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myJavaScriptCode()"]`.

In order for this to work you need to set the delegate on the `UIWebView` instance and implement the delegate method mentioned above so that the JavaScript is executed after the page has loaded.

The documentation for `- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script`  [can be found here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW21).

Now for the other part of your question (thanks for clarifying!).. to concatenate strings in Objective-C you can use the `NSString` class method `stringWithFormat:`.

For example, to pass two Objective-C values to a JavaScript string, you could do something like this:

```
// Substitute your Objective-C values into the string
NSString *javaScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"setVars('%@', '%@')", var1, var2, nil];

// Make the UIWebView method call
NSString *response = [webViewA stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
```

Comment: I am asking for script! I am properly making javascript calls with a single var but how to do it with two as explained? Thanks

Comment: Whoops, your question was a bit vague but thanks for clarifying. I've updated my answer with details :)