# rotation changed event, iPad, to HTML5

Tags: ios, objective-c, html

I am working on an iPad app, which has a UIWebview, which in turn hosts an html5 document that is saved locally and is not downloaded from the internet. 
I am handling the rotation changed event in obj c and doing the relevant UI changes for native iOS, I have another guy working on the html5 and he says that he is handling that event in CSS, my question is:
 can an html5 document loading within a UIWebview in an iOS app know that a rotation occurred? or is the iOS layer supposed to alert ( or notify ) the HTML5 layer of that?

How do people handle this situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility, is to execute javascript functions from iOS.

So for instance, on your view controller's `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` method, you could in turn call `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` on the UIWebView. This question talks about how to do that ([Calling Javascript using UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886443/calling-javascript-using-uiwebview)).

As far as the rotation and handling in CSS, here is a blog entry describing `@media` queries (https://mislav.net/2010/04/targeted-css/). I haven't tried the orientation queries, but I have used the other queries to target specific devices and screen types (i.e. retina).