# Hiding elements from UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I have a `UIWebView` in which I load a `NSURLRequest`. I do not have full control over the html for the page shown but I do know it will contain an element which has an id I happen to know beforehand. Let's say it is `submmit_form_button`.

I don't want the user of the app to see this element. I want to hide it before it appears to the user in the `UIWebView`.

What is the best option to do that? Where in the controller that shows the `UIWebView` should I put the code that will solve this? 
I am aware that I can use Javascript for this. I am more concerned about how can I approach this in the context of a native iOS app that shows a `UIWebView` which gets it's html from an external source.

Comment: By executing JavaScript on the page from UIWebView after it loads. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8886806/2089625)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the lead from the comment by @Ric I solved the problem with

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('submmit_form_button').style.display = 'none'"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to hide **multiple items** in same separate line with ";".

Here is example in Swift:-

```
let items = "document.getElementById('item_1').style.display='none';" 
            + "document.getElementById('item_2').style.display='none'"

webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: items)
```