# Detect end of youtube videos in UIWebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, youtube

I need to know when a youtube video has stopped playing. I looked up existing Q&As and all of them suggested redirecting to another unique URL which can be detected in webview load finished delegate.

But to do this I need to have a HTML page on server or in my app(since I need to add javascript functions for `onStateChange`). If its on server, server downtime will affect the app, if its in the app, any change would require an app update.

Is there any other workaround for this ?

EDIT: JS code which needs to be injected/loaded in html.

```
    var player;
    var videoID;
    var prmstr = window.location.search.substr(1);
    var prmarr = prmstr.split ("&");
    var params = {};

    for ( var i = 0; i < prmarr.length; i++) {
        var tmparr = prmarr[i].split("=");
        params[tmparr[0]] = tmparr[1];
    }
    if (params.videoID !== undefined || params.videoID !== "") {
        videoID = params.videoID;
    } else {
        videoID = "0Bmhjf0rKe8";
    }
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: videoID,
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }

    // autoplay video
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // when video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) {          
            window.location.href = "http://example.com/done.html";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can't you inject javascript into the page when it's loaded?  Then you can add whatever handlers you need.  Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886443/calling-javascript-using-uiwebview

Comment: @SB. If I have to inject JS, I need to inject above mentioned full code, as I have reference to only Embedded video id, which looks kinda messy if injected.