# How can i attach additional text into a UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

here is my problem:

I need to find a way to load / attach text into a UIWebView while staying at the scroll position so that the new text appears seamless when hitting a button.

The scenario is that i display a page of a book and when the user scrolls to the end of the page i need to present an option to attach the next page into the webView.

I tried loading the new NSString containing of both Strings into the webView and then i scroll it to the last position but that creates a ugly " flicker " and it is hard to keep an eye on the page break.

My question is if anyone has experience or an idea on how to create i " seamless scrolling " effect by loading more text into a UIWebview and attach it to the existing text without reloading the whole UIWebview. Unfortunately i am very unexperienced with Javascript but i hope there is a script that dynamically adds text to the existing content.

Something like the scrollView in iBooks.

If a potential helper needs any specific information please let me know, otherwise if anyone can point out a way to direct my research to i would be very grateful.

TA

Comment: this might helps you [stackoverflow link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886443/calling-javascript-using-uiwebview)

[techniques scroll](http://engineering.linkedin.com/linkedin-ipad-5-techniques-smooth-infinite-scrolling-html5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is most likely your best bet, as you suspected.  Luckily, adding text is easy.  You can have a script like this (assuming you have a node identified as `#myId` in your HTML):

```
function addText(textToAdd) {
   var div = document.getElementById('myId');
   div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + 'Extra stuff';
}
```

Then, you just need a way to call that function.  If you want to call it from your Obj-C code, you'll want to do something like:

`[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"addText('text to add')"];`

Of course, you could also use a framework like jQuery to further abstract the process of adding text to the existing HTML.  Check out the following link for a few examples of adding text using Javascript: [How to append data to div using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677799/how-to-append-data-to-div-using-javascript)

You may even want to or be able to do all the dynamic loading -- there are existing jQuery plugins for infinite scrolling already. (Google jQuery infinite scroll and peruse what's out there)

Comment: hey, even its ages ago. Thank you for your answer. I didn't end up implementing it yet but i will do so soon. This seems very straightforward, thanks for your explanation