# Execute JavaScript from iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

Let's say I have a web app which is designed for the desktop, and I want to create  simple and straightforward access for iOS. Consider it a simple form with a submit button.

Some options that would be great are:

1. Redesigning the web interface for mobile
2. Creating a REST-style
   API for access

Unfortunately neither of these options exist, so I have to create a wrapper in iOS. I have no problems creating the basic interface, authentication, etc...but now I need to be able to simulate selection of a radio button, maybe filling in a few fields, and clicking submit.

I'd like to capture those details in a native iOS interface (already done), and submit over the wire...the only practical theory I've heard of is to collect that info, pass it to a hidden UIWebView, and execute some JavaScript from the UIWebView...but I don't see any examples here, plus I want to make certain I'm on the right path.

Any ideas?

Comment: you are getting down voted because A) you should make a native app or B) implement a mobile friendly web front end. I'm not sure what the ruling is for UIWebView wrapper apps going into the app store but thats going to be a bad UX imo.

Comment: You question is a little bit confusing. But you should look at WKWebviews which are/will be the replacement for UIWebViews and WebViews.   Data can pass back and forth between app and WKWebviews as well as sending Javascript calls via callback to the WKWebviews  a WKWebviews can do the same to the app, therefore controlling the app and any other WKWebviews  in it. Have look at this to see what I mean.  http://forums.tumult.com/t/get-control-of-feedback-from-webpage-or-ios-mac-app-using-the-newish-wkwebview/3503/6?u=markhunte

Comment: Solved it myself, using a hidden UIWebView which calls Javascript to manipulate the page elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Implement the UIWebView's delegate method webViewDidFinishLoad: in
>   your UIViewController and in there you call [graphView
>   stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"methodName()"]; to make sure
>   the function gets called after the page has been loaded.

[Calling Javascript using UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886443/calling-javascript-using-uiwebview)

Comment: Thanks - figured it out this morning, but pretty much what I did!

Comment: Nice work, please mark my answer as correct if it helped.

Comment: Done; I wish the docs were more clear on this, but that's always the case!