# How to hide div element in UIWebView Swift 3

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, swift3, xcode8

I have code like this

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        let loadStyles = "document.getElementById('platforms').style.display = 'none';"
        webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: loadStyles)
    }
```

but it's not work in Frame UIWebView. I want to hide the div within the frame on UIWebView. If I change "alert('Hallo World')" in let LoadStyles this code call when app opened. I feel so confused.

please provide me with a solution if you can. Thanks

[top up saldo paypal](https://jualsaldo.com)

Answer (score 1):

Using `UIWebView` isn't recommended in newest versions of iOS. That what Apple [says](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview):

> **Important**
>
> Starting in iOS 8.0 and OS X 10.10, use WKWebView to add web content to your app. Do not use UIWebView or WebView.

Try to implement the same thing using `WKWebView`, it works much better with js. I'm sure this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Use WKWebView, it is the modern version. Then you could use "evaluateJavaScript", it works perfect.

Read more in my response:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42239272/7565959