# How to set the local storage before a UIWebView loading its initial request?

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uiwebview

#### ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let wv = UIWebView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        wv.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "localStorage.setItem('key', 'value')")
        wv.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://localhost:63343/test.html")!))
        self.view.addSubview(wv)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
}
```

#### test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script>
        alert(localStorage.getItem("key"))
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I called `localStorage.setItem('key', 'value')` before `loadRequest`. I expect that alert will output `value`, but it outputed `null`:

[image]

So my question:

What's the correct way to set the local storage before a `UIWebView` loading its initial request?

EDIT:

Thank @Wez for pointing out I should evaluate JavaScript in `webViewDidFinishLoad`, but What I want to do is setting that localStorage before that page loaded(we will use that localStorage in its initial request). So I can't evaluate it in webViewDidFinishLoad...

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: You need to wait for the page to load before you can evaluate the Javascript. I think this may be a duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling Javascript using UIWebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886443/calling-javascript-using-uiwebview)

Comment: @Wez But I want to set that localStorage before that page loaded(we will use that localStorage in its initial request). So I can't evaluate it in `webViewDidFinishLoad`...

Comment: did you ever find a way to set items to localstorage BEFORE a webview finish loading @Sayakiss

Answer (score 3):

In case you're looking for a **Swift** version:

```
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
let contentController = WKUserContentController()
let js = "javascript: localStorage.setItem('key', 'value')"
let userScript = WKUserScript(source: js, injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: false)
contentController.addUserScript(userScript)
configuration.userContentController = contentController

let webview = WKWebView(configuration: configuration)
webview.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "your URL")))
```

Comment: use localStorage in web view works if I close and open the app? the value is saved? or I must active it someway? thanks

Comment: You are missing this line `configuration.userContentController = contentController`

Comment: Great Answer!. Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use WKWebView instead UIWebView and load the script. take a look in this sample, I created in C# but you can translate it to Objetive-c/Swift

```
        var configuration = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
        var contentController = new WKUserContentController();
        string js = "javascript: localStorage.setItem('key', 'value')";
        var userScript = new WKUserScript((NSString)js, WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentStart, false);
        contentController.AddUserScript(userScript);
        configuration.UserContentController = contentController;

        WKWebView _wKWebView = new WKWebView(this.View.Frame,configuration);
        var url = "Your Url";
        var webViewRequest = new NSMutableUrlRequest(new Foundation.NSUrl(url));
        _wKWebView.LoadRequest(webViewRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Localhost doesn't work try this one:**

```
wv.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://10.0.2.2:63343/test.html")!))
```