# How do I get HTML5 localstorage data to the native code by cordova on ios?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cordova

I'm developing an app using CORDOVA and I am using localstorage in javascript

Can I use Cordova to access local storage in webview directly?

I looked at the documentation on the https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/  but couldn't find it.

---

Javascript code -

```
 window.localStorage.setItem("test", "hello World");
```

ios native code - 
  I want

```
       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; get("test");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it works on ios in javascript, to get the value :

```
window.localStorage.getItem("test");
```

more from cordova docs https://cordova.apache.org/docs/fr/latest/cordova/storage/localstorage/localstorage.html :

```
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        window.localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
        var keyname = window.localStorage.key(i);
        // keyname is now equal to "key"
        var value = window.localStorage.getItem("key");
        // value is now equal to "value"
        window.localStorage.removeItem("key");
        window.localStorage.setItem("key2", "value2");
        window.localStorage.clear();
        // localStorage is now empty
    }
```

to read :

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/73

[How to set the local storage before a UIWebView loading its initial request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622192/how-to-set-the-local-storage-before-a-uiwebview-loading-its-initial-request)

Comment: This is not native code... 
This is JavaScript code

I want objective-c code

Comment: you can execute JS with evaluateJavascript  function, please look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46082813/ios-objective-c-localstore-in-wkwebview