# how to access server side javascript from from swift

Tags: swift

//this is my website on server

let url=url(string://"https://xyz.aspx")

```
let urlRequest:URLRequest=URLRequest(url:url!)

WebView.loadRequest(urlRequest)

//I want to call LoginByMobileApp() javascript function from swift

 WebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from:"LoginByMobileApp()")
```

Comment: Try this solution  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886443/calling-javascript-using-uiwebview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call java script function when webview didfinishload, before that your javascript function is not called..

```
import UIKit

class yourViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var webView : UIWebView

    var url = URL(string: "https://xyz.aspx")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //load initial URL
        var req = URLRequest(URL : url)
        WebView.delegate = self
        webView.loadRequest(req)
    }
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView : UIWebView) {
         WebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from:"LoginByMobileApp()")
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Er. Khatri check the image in top of the question.

Comment: you have done it using WKWebView.., you can also use UIWebView to call javascripts in iOS

Comment: @jakirhussain try the above answer once.., I am sure your LoginByMobileApp() function will be successfully called

Answer (score 0):

You could use `evaluateJavaScript` function for `WKWebView`.

let javaScriptString = "YOUR_JAVASCRIPT_FUNCTION"

```
 webView.evaluateJavaScript(javaScriptString, completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: I'm using @IBOutlet weak var WebView: UIWebView!

Comment: You cannot do it using UIWebView. Migrate to WKWebView.

Comment: after using this I am getting value=nil and error = nil

Comment: Could you expalin more? Which value and error you are talking about

Comment: how to call JavaScript using WKWebView on  DidFinishLoad  
@ Fares Ben Hamouda